# Dropping tables, with no backing domain classes, on application shutdown

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, grails, grails-orm

I would like to drop tables upon application shutdown, which I created on-the-fly during startup of the application. There are no `Domain` classes for those.

I used `destroy` closure available in in `Bootstrap.groovy`, like this

```
def someService
...
...
def destroy = {
    String dbCreate = Holders.grailsApplication.config.getProperty('dataSource.dbCreate', String)
    if(dbCreate == 'create-drop')
        someService.drop(customTables) // customTables is a List of names
}
```

`drop()` method in service looks like,

```
void drop(List<String> tables) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.currentSession // Getting exception on this line
    tables.each {
        session.createSQLQuery("drop table if exists $it").executeUpdate()
    }
}
```

I'm getting,

> Error occurred running Bootstrap destroy method: No Session found for
>   current thread
>
> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:116)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:688)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor492.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)

Note: Grails, 3.2.8

Comment: Not sure what are you doing. According to http://docs.grails.org/3.2.8/guide/conf.html#_more_on_dbcreate `create-drop - Same as create, but also drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly.`

Comment: Yes, but I don't have Domains backing those tables; so, Hibernate doesn't know those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a kind of work around; moved that bit in `init`, like below

```
def init = {
    String dbCreate = Holders.grailsApplication.config.getProperty('dataSource.dbCreate', String)
    if(dbCreate == 'create-drop') 
        baseSeqService.drop(customTables)
    baseSeqService.create(customTables)    
    ...
}
```

Comment: This may be a better approach as you might not always have a clean shutdown that calls destroy.

Comment: Yes; however, an abnormal, or unclean, shutdown would also refrain Hibernate from dropping the tables. So, that's fine with me.